# Can the compiler omit a redundant if statement if the condition is known in this case?

Tags: c++, optimization

In the following examples there are two conditional checks but I assume if the compiler inlines the code there only need be one, is that correct?

```
bool f(bool b)
{
    if (b) return true;
    else return false;

}

std::unordered_map<int, int> my_map;
bool find(int id)
{
    auto it = my_map.find(id);
    if (it != my_map.end()) return true;
    else return false;

}

int main()
{
    if (f(true))
        std::cout << "It was true\n";

    if (find(1))
        std::cout << "Contains key\n";
)
```

Also would it matter if the argument is passed as value or reference?

Comment: The compiler is _allowed_ to make any transformation that doesn't alter the externally observable behavior of the code, but whether it actually does so depends on the compiler, the circumstances, the switches used, and so on.

Comment: [The *as-if rule*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) gives compilers quite a lot of room to do things like that.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but `if(b) return true; else return false;` should be written `return b;`. They both mean the same thing, but the latter is much more concise and clear. Similarly, `return it != my_map.end();`.

Comment: For the first, yes, this is a trivial case, compilers *can* do this optimization and most mainstream compiler *certainly will*. For the second, this is much more complex because of the global variable. AFAIK, compilers *cannot* do this optimization unless this file is the only one compiled. If you use a two step compilation, then *linker optimisation* (like `-fwhole-program` for the GNU one) are needed to ensure there is nothing modifying the global variable in our back. Using reference does not change anything except if the referenced variable comes from an untraceable source.